# What query can give me this result?

Tags: sql-server

I have these three tables:

#### Table1

```
pro_id(Pk)  pro_name   
1           ABC           
2           def
```

#### Table2

```
pid pro_id               
1   1                      
2   1                      
3   1                                                 
4   2                                                 
5   2
6   2
```

#### Table3

```
pro_id  code
1       dc23
1       ef45
2       456F
2       4er
```

How can I write a query that would give this result?

```
pro_id    noof pids  noofcodes
1         3          2
2         3          2
```

Answer (score 4):

The following would do it. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4af615/1)

```
WITH T2
     AS (SELECT pro_id,
                COUNT(pid) AS [noof pids]
         FROM   Table2
         GROUP  BY pro_id),
     T3
     AS (SELECT pro_id,
                COUNT(code) noofcodes
         FROM   Table3
         GROUP  BY pro_id)
SELECT T1.pro_id,
       COALESCE([noof pids], 0) AS [noof pids],
       COALESCE(noofcodes, 0)   AS noofcodes
FROM   Table1 T1
       LEFT JOIN T2
         ON T1.pro_id = T2.pro_id
       LEFT JOIN T3
         ON T1.pro_id = T3.pro_id
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also just use two scalar subqueries:

```
SELECT pro_id,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2 WHERE pro_id=A.pro_id) [noof pids],
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table3 WHERE pro_id=A.pro_id) [noofcodes]
  FROM Table1 A;
```